# Dynamic change properties of form field in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have this piece of code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', ['required' => true])
        ->add('item', ['required' => true])
        ->add('isItem', ['empty_value' => true])
        ->sdd('submit')
    ;
}
```

Where: **name** and **item** are strings, **isItem** is boolean field. I want to change dynamically properties of **item** field based on the **isItem** value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achieved by using `Form Events` ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html)).

You could, for example, listen to the `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` event like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', ['required' => true])
        ->add('item', ['required' => true])
        ->add('isItem', ['empty_value' => true])
        ->sdd('submit')
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));
}

public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data   = $event->getData();
    $form   = $event->getForm();
    $entity = $form->getData();

    if ($data['isItem']) {
        // do something
    } else
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's good solution. But in my example I had to use 

    if (isset($data['isItem'])

instead:

    if ($data['isItem'])